# Force keyboard to appear

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

How can I cause the keyboard to appear on my website?
It's a javascript script that reads keyboard input, but I cannot get the keyboard to be shown on my mobile device.

Is there something that "fakes" standard input, and lets key events to be triggered?

I need to say that what am I trying to do is to enable the keyboard on jCubic terminal emulator: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: you could combine window.onload with onblur

Answer (score 1):

You can do that the following way:

- `prompt()` opens the keyboard
- If you trigger `.focus()` from within a `.click()` event (e.g. from opening your dialog), the keyboard shows up

For Android and iOS, `.focus()` seems to work just fine, but you have to wait for the page to fully render.

See this example:

```js
function focus() {
  $('input').focus();
}

$(function() {
  focus();

  $(document.body).load(focus);
  $('#click').click(focus);
  $('#click-timeout').click(function() {
    setTimeout(focus, 1000);
  });
  $('#mousedown').mousedown(focus);
  $('#mousedown-timeout').mousedown(function() {
    setTimeout(focus, 1000);
  });
  $('#mouseup').mouseup(focus);
  $('#mouseup-timeout').mouseup(function() {
    setTimeout(focus, 1000);
  });
  $('#extern-click-trigger').click(function() {
    $('#click').click();
  });
  $('#tap').bind('tapone', function() {
    focus();
  });
  $('#tap-triggering-click').bind('tapone', function() {
    $('#click').click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<p id="click">Click handler</p>
<p id="click-timeout">Click handler setting timeout</p>
<p id="mousedown">Mousedown handler</p>
<p id="mousedown-timeout">Mousedown handler setting timeout</p>
<p id="mouseup">Mouseup handler</p>
<p id="mouseup-timeout">Mouseup handler setting timeout</p>
<p id="extern-click-trigger">Clicking here will trigger click on the first 'Click Handler'</p>
<p id="tap">Virtual 'TAP' handler</p>
<p id="tap-triggering-click">Virtual 'TAP' handler triggering click on the first 'Click handler'</p>
```

Comment: Do you want a fake keyboard you mean?